# "Move from a city" vs. "move out of a city"

Tags: prepositions, difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *move from a city* and *move out of a city*? For example:

> I lived in the city for a couple of years but decided to **move from it** to live in a small town.
>
> I lived in the city for a couple of years but decided to **move out of it** to live in a small town.

Are both perfectly natural and correct?

Comment: You can _move from_ any place of any size, but if you move from within an urban area to somewhere more rural you might speak of _moving out_ of the city.